# combobox properties to allow user to type text in it and let it filter by text entered

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox where I'll need to allow user to search by text and be able to select that value from the list. So what I'm currently doing is, on CBO_KeyPress, I open the drop down.

```
Me.cboNames.DroppedDown = True
```

I set the property of the cbo...

```
AutoCompleteMode=SuggestAppend
DropDownStyle = DropDown
AutoCompleteSource=ListItems
```

Everything works beautifully except for one issue. As it stands, i have items in the drop down where the width is significantly wider than the combobox - I have a function that adjusts the DropDownWith to longest string in the list of items. My concern is that while this helps user search for correct item, it's width is only as wide as the combobox.  Is there a way to adjust this?

My only other option is to not use `AutoCompleteSource=ListItems` and instead simply open the dropDown programmatically on KeyPress or something. In this case, it doesn't do as good of a job of filtering the items. AutoCompleteSource does it beautifully but the width issue does not make it look right.

**EDIT :** Plutonix - here's what I did. I changed `AutoCompleteSource=None`. On `CboName_KeyPress` I open dropdown programmatically. Now I type in text, see image below....

[image]

It doesn't find text 100% of the time as you can see. AutoCompleteSource narrows it down and only shows you the items that begin with the same text as typed by user but the width is the issue. It actually looks much better with AutoCompleteSource because if they type in text that's not in the list of items then it shows nothing - and user known it's not in the list.

Users tab into the filed and start typing text. They don't open it. That's why they want this to be updated like that. I want them to see the items as they type in.

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing.  If they type some text that exists, when they open the CBO it will automatically look for an item like that.  If they open the CBO and type, it will keep putting the closest match at the top.  No need for the autocomplete aspect, AFAICT

Comment: @plutonix - see edit

Comment: @plutonix - did i clear up what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If there is not enough items in the list for the closest match to scroll to the top, it will still scroll it into view; its the best it can do given the data.

Comment: @plutonix - but is there no way to adjust the width of the AutoCompleteSource? when it' set to ListItems. It basically opens up showing the closest matches given the text in the cbo, but it's width is only as wide as cbo?

Comment: @plutonix - sorry to jump at you with all these questions - when AutoCompleteSource is set to NONE - then if i type text in the cbo and tab off it, it basically disappears (even though I don't clear it or anything) basically check if cboName.text<>"" - but my _Leave event still recognizes that there's text in the cbo

Comment: When you use AutoComplete, notice that there is a doodad at the bottom for the user to resize it (called a 'grip')  The control will remember the user's selection each time.  If you want to manually control it (**not** recommended) you will need a bunch of PInvoke code of the type you have yakked at before and scorned us for offering.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but there is a property called **DropDownWidth**

Comment: @steve - yes I know that. I have a function that adjusts the width of DROPDOWNWIDTH when it's opened. However, this doesn't seem to work with AutoCompleteSource.

Comment: @Steve the auto list overlays the real DDL and has its own way of doing things

Comment: @steve the problem with this is as you can see in the image it doesn't show the matching text - the first item in the dropdown list. Now the problem is when I don't use AutoCompleteSource and  I tab off the cbo, the text disappears, however is still recognized in the LEAVE event when I check for cboNames.Text. I dont know why it's doing that